# I have error in one machine from ORACLE cluster

Tags: oracle, listener, tnsnames, tns

I am using Oracle 10g Cluster. So, the listener on 1 Oracle machine hasn't been working for a week now. I get an error:

```
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

When I want to start listener from oracle user, listener started without services.

```
lsnrctl status
```

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on 08-NOV-2021 11:05:53

Copyright (c) 1991, 2006, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
Start Date                02-NOV-2021 09:12:26
Uptime                    6 days 1 hr. 53 min. 26 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      ON
Listener Parameter File   /oracle/10.2.0/db/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /oracle/10.2.0/db/network/log/listener_amrac1.log
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=amrac1)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

But database not working.

I am not changed IP, names of machines, etc.

Please help resolve issue.

Comment: What happens when you start the Oracle database itself? The listener is not of much use if the database isn't up and running.

Comment: I cannot start database. For now database has status
srvctl status database -d amd
PRKH-1010 : Unable to communicate with CRS services.
[OCR Error(Native: prsr_initCLSS:[21])]
PRKO-2005 : Application error: Failure in getting Cluster Database Configuration for: amd

Comment: Now I am started database on the 2nd machine.
So, I have last problem that tns on the 1st machine not started

`code`
srvctl status database -d amd
PRKH-1010 : Unable to communicate with CRS services.
  [OCR Error(Native: prsr_initCLSS:[21])]
PRKO-2005 : Application error: Failure in getting Cluster Database Configuration for: amd
`code`

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Please add relevant information to the question itself and not in comments. Hit [edit] and convert you comments into readable information in your question. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you perform a `TNSPING <SID>` or `TNSPING <SERVICE_ID>`  on the bash prompt? Do you receive a response?  Add the response of the `TNSPING` to your [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/302289/edit).

Answer (score -1):

So, the issue was resolved:

1. the 1st problem was that on the cluster not a mounted DB disk. I am restarted MSA.
2. ocr files was differented between 2 machines. I am changed it and restarted machines with DB.

Comment: This isn't terribly useful for anyone else. Are you intending to update this answer to help someone else with a similar problem in future? Or are you going to delete the question?